# What are the differences between single and double annular combustion chambers?

Tags: jet-engine, combustion

The combustion chamber of a jet engine may be can type or annular type. Annular type combustion chamber can be SAC (single annular combustion chamber) or DAC (double annular combustion chamber). What are the major changes between these  two types of combustion chamber? Is the CFM56-7B26 a SAC or DAC engine?

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44869/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-dual-annular-combustor?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the difference between a SAC and DAC combustor. The EASA type certificate for the [CFM56-7](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/EASA-TCDS-E.004_CFM_International_S.A._--_CFM56--7B_series_engines-04-17122012.pdf) also identifies which engines have the DAC and which have the SAC. The answer depends on exactly which -7B26 version you are referring to.